# How to build android project with jenkins?

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I've been trying to setup jenkins to build a gradle based android project.

Here's what I have done so far :

1. Launched an EC2 Instance with Jenkins Stack by Bitnami.
2. Successfully tested a job that prints "uptime" every minute.
3. Installed Android SDK Tools.

But now when I configured a job to build the android project with it, I get a weird exception, which I think is related to some permissions on my ubuntu machine.

Here is the stack trace :

```
    First time build. Skipping changelog.
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/temp/hudson1533897385497543877.sh
+ whoami
tomcat
+ echo Starting Build
Starting Build
[Gradle] - Launching build.
[workspace] $ gradle clean
Could not load Logmanager "org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.JavaUtilLoggingConfigurer.configure(JavaUtilLoggingConfigurer.java:36)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingConfigurer.configure(DefaultLoggingConfigurer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.LoggingSystemAdapter.setLevel(LoggingSystemAdapter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.LoggingSystemAdapter.on(LoggingSystemAdapter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager$StartableLoggingSystem.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:191)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:60)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to create parent directory '/opt/bitnami/.gradle/caches/2.6/scripts' when creating directory '/opt/bitnami/.gradle/caches/2.6/scripts/settings_i62l96mhihwg5udfskdyy53h/cp_settings'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.27 secs
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Ready to furnish any other information required by anyone. Please suggest what should I do.

Comment: See if this helps - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h74i7krG33Y . I was able to setup jenkins on my system following this video.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with jenkins for a long time now and this could be from lots of reasons. first I'd check the environment variables of jenkins. add a build setp echo $PATH because this looks to me like java can't find some libraries. Compare this PATH variable with your local one. Also, after installing any thing new make sure to do http://{your_jenkins_url}/restart.

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to: https://community.bitnami.com/t/gradle-user-home-opt-bitnami-gradle/40717

The bitnami jenkins/gradle setup, by default, seems to point GRADLE_USER_HOME to a directory not writable by jenkins/gradle, and so various downloads/caches fail in mysterious ways.